# How do I get the length of a String in C++?

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sending binary data as a String.  It's easy to publish it and read it in Python, but I'm trying to extend a driver that's written in C++ (and I have very little C++ experience).  I made it work by using this ugly kludge in the topic subscriber.

```
uint32_t string_length = ros::serialization::serializationLength(*msg) - 4;
```

I was hoping that there would be a length value in the message but according to http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29 String only has one member, "data".  Is there a clean way to get the length of the data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282208/how-do-i-get-the-length-of-a-string-in-c++?/) by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar to python's `len()` method for determining the length of a string, the `std::string` object in C++ has a `length()` member function that returns the length of the string. (See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ for more complete documentation of `std::string`)

Since the string in a std_msgs/String message is represented with a `std::string` in C++, if you have a pointer to a `std_msgs::String` (the C++ type for std_msgs/String) you can get the string's length with `msg->data.length()`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) on 2018-02-09**:
Perfect.  That is exactly the answer I needed and the reference will help me with other work.  I updated the code and it works as expected.  Thank you!